# registration question for facebook plugin

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, registration

how large can the custom fields be in the social plugin from facebook? How many characters?  Can I program it to ask a short question and get them to reply with a few sentences?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits posted that I have seen, but I can tell you that there is a limit as to the length of the JSON that is used for the creation of the custom fields. Once you hit a certain length (I have not been able to find it exactly, but much shorter than I wanted), it returns hard to decipher errors - if thats the case, try shortening the request.

To bring this around to your question, you should be able to ask a short question and get a response. I will warn you that you do not have a ton of control over the size or style, so you may run into issues where it is expecting shorter values, and your text area may not be large enough to show all of their answer as they are typing it.